# bestfit nonlinear to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of data frames and I would like to calculate the nonlinear bestfit to each dataframe in the list and to get a list with the best fit objects. I am trying to use lapply but I am having problems with the parameters.

```
# define a function for D
fncTtr <- function(n,d) (d/n)*((sqrt(1+2*(n/d))-1))
# define a function for best fit
bestFitD <- function(dat,fun) {
 res <- nls(dat$ttr~fun(n,d),data=dat,start=list(d=25),trace=T)
 return(res)
}

resL <- lapply(dData2,bestFitD,dat=dData2,fun=fncTtr)
```

When I execute this code I am getting the following error:

> Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : unused argument(s) (X[[1]])

I want the lapply to go thru each dataframe in dData2 and to execute the bestFitD function. How should I define the parameters for the function in lapply. The dData2 object is a list. I am using it as a parameter for bestFitD but this function expects one dataframe as a parameter. How can I define this parameter? When I execute the function bestFitD by itself with one dataframe, it is running correctly. example of a dData2 list with components that are dataframes:

```
$`1`
    n    ttr      d id
1  35 0.6951 27.739  1
2  36 0.6925 28.072  1
3  37 0.6905 28.507  1
4  38 0.6887 28.946  1
5  39 0.6790 28.003  1
6  40 0.6703 27.247  1
7  41 0.6566 25.735  1
8  42 0.6605 26.981  1
9  43 0.6567 27.016  1
10 44 0.6466 26.026  1
11 45 0.6531 27.667  1
12 46 0.6461 27.128  1
13 47 0.6336 25.751  1
14 48 0.6225 24.636  1
15 49 0.6214 24.992  1
16 50 0.6248 26.011  1

$`2`
    n    ttr      d id
17 35 0.6951 27.739  2
18 36 0.6925 28.072  2
19 37 0.6905 28.507  2
20 42 0.6605 26.981  2
```

The following code seems to be ok:

```
res <- bestFitD(dData2[[1]],fncTtr)
```

but when I execute the following:

```
res <- bestFitD(dData2[[2]],fncTtr)
```

I am getting the followin error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~dat + ttr + n, data = dat) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'dat'
```

Why? Both are dataframes!
But it seems that There is something strange with the second component!

Comment: Can you please add a sample of a data.frame when nls it works?

Comment: With what you've provided my only suggestion is to try `resL <- lapply(dData2, function(x) bestFitD(dat = x,fun = fncTtr)` to see if it works.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I got the following error:Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~dat + ttr + n, data = dat) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'dat'

Comment: @user963386 yes well that's not `lapply`'s fault anymore.  try `bestFitD( dData2[[2]] , fun = fncTtr )` -- same error

Comment: I agree that it is not a problem with lapply in this case. But it is strange that it works ok with dData[[1]] but I get the error when I run dData[[2]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just get rid of the `dat$` in your `nls` function call.  i believe it's looking for `dat$dat$ttr` which obviously will break. That is, your `bestFitD` function should be:

```
bestFitD <- function(dat,fun) {
    res <- nls(ttr~fun(n,d),data=dat,start=list(d=25),trace=T)
    return(res)
}
```

Now, call using `lapply` as:

```
resL <- lapply(dData2, bestFitD, fun = fncTtr)
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Your solution is working and it has a good explanation and it is similar to what I had done!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
resL <- lapply(dData2, function(x,fun){
                 bestFitD(x,fun)
               },fun='fncTtr')
```

Where I rewrite,bestFitD  using `do.call`

```
bestFitD <- function(dat,fun){
  nls(ttr~do.call(fun,list(n,d)), data=dat,
      start=list(d=25),trace=T)
  res
}

0.003237457 :  25 
0.0009393089 :  26.77943 
0.0009362902 :  26.84895 
0.0009362902 :  26.84898 
0.001282807 :  25 
4.771935e-05 :  27.64267 
4.389588e-05 :  27.80729 
4.389584e-05 :  27.80781
```

**EDIT**

my solution can be simplified to (similar but not exactly to Anthony solution)

```
lapply(dData2, bestFitD, fun = 'fncTtr')
```

Comment: Thanks agstudy. Your solution is working but it is a little more complicated.